# Error "Authentication error. Please log back to authenticate" uploading artifact to bluemix with Java Buildpack

Tags: java, tomcat, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud-tools

After doing login in bluemix I tried to upload a java artifact to bluemix with the Cloud Foundry java buildpack and I always get this message;

> FAILED Authentication has expired.  Please log back in to
> re-authenticate.

I have tried to logout and login many times (using "manual account login" and "api key login"). Login is always OK but the error persists. This is the bluemix login result

> API endpoint:     https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net (API version: 2.92.0)
>
> Region:           eu-de
>
> User:             irivera@tripbru.com
>
> Account:          *Account name* (*account id*) <-> *other*
>
> Resource group:   default
>
> Org:              selected org
>
> Space:            selected space

Also I checked the time sync and is synchronised with ntp (no problem).
I´m in spain and trying to upload to Bluemix Germany

Tried to uninstall bluemix client deleting all files before and no result

This problem began yesterday, but just one hours before I uploaded a lot of artifacts in distinct apps without any problem (including the "now in error app")

Comment: When you say "uploading an artifact", are you pushing an application that has a large artifact?  Exactly how are you "uploading"?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with a "trick". Seems to exist any "intermitent" problem with apps already deployed to bluemix.

First, delete the app from control panel (or remove with CLI). You have to ensure that not only the app was deleted, also that the route must not exists (I think that this is the real problem).

After clearing all "records" of the already deployed app, the new version can be deployed again without problems.

Now this problem happens once or twice a week. it´s not a solution, but at least I can continue deploying app versions